# PyQt5 disable text editing but keep scrolling

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt5, qtextedit

I have a QTextEdit into which I load HTML text. This Text should only be presented and not be editable.

I've tried the method `setDisable(True)`, but this will also disable the scrolling of the QTextEdit area.

Is there a way to disable the text editing but still keep the scrolling?

Comment: Does  `setReadonly(True)` work?

Comment: Yes that was it thanks!

Comment: Use `QTextBrowser`.